# Imagemagick converting .pdf to grayscale .png results in a black image

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, png, ghostscript

I have been using the following command to convert a pdf file into a grayscale png:

```
magick.exe convert -density 300 +antialias -quality 100 -type grayscale test1.pdf test1.png
```

It worked fine, until I came along a pdf file created by Microsoft Word 365. The source file contains a logo and some text, but the result is nothing but a black box. Using a pdfinfo.exe, I get the following information from the pdf:

```
Title:          XXXX
Author:         XX
Creator:        Microsoft« Word for Microsoft 365
Producer:       Microsoft« Word for Microsoft 365
CreationDate:   08/30/21 10:10:10
ModDate:        08/30/21 10:10:10
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          6
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.32 x 842.04 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      208803 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.7
```

I'm using the latest version of imagemagick.exe:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-8 Q16-HDRI x64 2021-09-18 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenCL
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg jxl lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raqm raw rsvg tiff webp xml zip zlib
Compiler: Visual Studio 2019 (192930133)
```

I'm wondering if this is in fact a GhostScript related issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't comment usefully without seeing the PDF file and looking at its content. Have you tried using Ghostscript on the file directly (use the pnggray device) ? Do you know what ImageMagick uses for parameters to Ghostscript ? What version of Ghostscript are you using ?

Comment: You have gslib (Ghostscript) installed. So unless it is an older buggy version this command should work. `magick.exe -density 300 test1.pdf -colorspace gray  test1.png` Use magick.exe, not magick.exe convert.